# CiviMail and Sparkpost Bounces Not Updating email address "On Hold"

Tags: civimail, bounce, sparkpost

We have been using the SparkPost extension (civi desk) about a month and it is sending emails fine.  However, it may not be processing bounces completely and/or I do not understand how it works.  If we get a hard bounce should the contact's email address be placed "On Hold"?  I am getting bounces documented in the CiviMail Reports for a mailing. The only bounce type I see in these reports is "Syntax".  These emails are not getting placed "On Hold".  Should they be placed on hold automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There's a forum discussion [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=21512.0) which I think helps towards the answer.  If you look at the table civicrm_mailing_bounce_type there's a threshold of 3 for bounce type 'Syntax'.  I just encountered a bounce for type 'Host' that didn't place the email address on hold, so was also concerned as to why.  The answer is in this table.